# Pre-Birthday Selection

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

I´d like to send a pre-birthday mail 1 week before the birthday. Therefore I need the SQL statement.

Right now it looks like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterAbonnenten 
WHERE  DAY([Birthday]) = DAY(GETUTCDATE())
AND MONTH([Birthday]) = MONTH(GETUTCDATE()) 
AND Newsletter = 'true'
```

Could someone help me! Thanks!

Comment: What kind of field is birthday? A Date field or a string field? You would search for tsql functions like getdate(), dateadd(), datepart(). Just search for these functions and read what their arguments can be.

Comment: and also mention in which timezone you want this to be processed (remember that marketing cloud has CET standard time)